# MySQL to Postgres data migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm in the process of migrating a Ruby on Rails application from MySQL to Postgres. Is there a recommended way to keep the *deleted data*, like all the deleted records (their IDs at least) from MySQL?

In testing a dump-and-restore didn't seem to keep deleted records.

Also, in the event that I manage to keep the records where they are, what'll happen with the blank ones in Postgres? Will they be skipped over or used?

**Example**

Say I have a `user` with an ID of `101` and I've deleted `users` up to `100`. I need `101` to stay at `101`.

Comment: If data is deleted, it doesn't exist in the DB anymore, so you can't keep it. This doesn't make sense. Are you talking about `AUTO_INCREMENT` keys and PostgreSQL `SERIAL` columns?

Comment: I'll update the question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't want to reassign the IDs assigned to records where you generated keys.

That should be the default in any sane migration. When you copy the data rows over - say, exporting from MySQL with `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and importing into PostgreSQL with `COPY tablename FROM 'filename.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV)`, the IDs won't change.

All you'll need to do is to set the next ID to be generated in the sequence on the PostgreSQL table afterwards. So, say you have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null,
    ...
);
```

and you've just copied a user with `id` = `101` into it.

You'll now just assign a new value to the *key generation sequence* for the table, e.g.:

```
SELECT setval('users_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM users)+1);
```

To learn more about sequences and key generation in PostgreSQL, see [`SERIAL` in the numeric types documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html), the documentation for [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html), the docs for [`setval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html), etc. The default name for a key generation sequence is `tablename_columnname_seq`.

Comment: Oh good! I started to panic when I thought this might be a problem. Will I have to assign new values to the key generation sequence for every table individually?

Comment: @emm Yep. I'd script it personally. The above assumes you're migrating the data table-by-table as CSV. If you're using some kind of Rails-level data migration then everything might be different.